# Lambda function failed to stabilize since it is in InProgress state

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

We've been experiencing issues with `DockerImageFunction`. All deployments fail with the following (and very cryptic to me) error:

> Lambda function XXX failed to stabilize since it is in InProgress state

Other functions deploy without any problems. Deployments were working fine until Wednesday 07.04.2021. Since then, they fail every time. We haven't changed anything in our CDK code, in that function Dockerfile or its code.

We deploy using cdk typescript. I tested with 1.93 and 1.97 (latest version at the time of this writing).

Any clue ?

Comment: Just open a support ticket

Comment: What does it look like in the AWS cloudformation console?

Comment: Sounds like it thinks it is currently being deployed, not sure if you can experience any downtime on the lambda but you could try remove it from cdk code, do a deploy so it deletes, then put it back in an deploy it again

Comment: Seeing the same "failed to stabilize since it's in InProgress state" error when deploying a DockerImageFunction as of the last couple of days. As you experienced, other functions in the stack deploy OK. I'll post back if I find a resolution. Appreciate if others here do the same.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue and working with AWS Support. The error I am getting using Lambda Container is and there is an escalated case with the Lambda team.  with  Resource handler returned message: "Lambda function XXXX failed to stabilize since it is in InProgress state" (RequestToken: XXXX, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized).

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a bug that Amazon will need to resolve. However...

In the event someone needs a ***temporary workaround*** to deploy their CDK stack which includes a DockerImageFunction and they do not want to delete the whole stack first (perhaps because some resources are S3 buckets with important data), here are some steps that worked for me. This assumes your stack is in the state described above, i.e. an update has failed, the system attempted a rollback, and then the update rollback also failed.

1. From the CloudFormation console select "Continue update rollback"
2. Select "advanced options" and choose to skip the function or functions that use the containerized deployment (i.e. DockerImageFunctions)
3. The rollback should now complete successfully
4. If you try to deploy again now the stack will return to the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state again, so don't bother. Instead comment out all the code that instantiates and references the DockerImageFunctions in your CDK stack class. Then perform the deployment, which should remove those functions and their various roles and permissions from the CloudFormation stack.
5. Once this is complete you can uncomment all the stack code you just commented out and perform a final deploy. This one should succeed. It did for me at least: all the latest version of my application is deployed.

It seem likely that if I perform another deploy after this the same error will occur and I will have to go through these five steps again. I haven't tried it yet. But at least this is workaround, however clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - This issue should be resolve. Confirmed with AWS support and our stacks.